# Split sentence by “words”, treating multiple capital words (assumed to be proper nouns) as one

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to split a string, where multi-word proper nouns are recognized as one token. For example, the following code needs to be changed,

```
import re

s = 'Multi-Criteria Decision Making (MCDM) is increasingly used in RE projects.'
out = re.compile("\s").split(s)

print(out)
```

in order to get this desired outcome:

```
['Multi-Criteria Decision Making', 'MCDM', 'is', 'increasingly', 'used', 'in', 'RE', 'projects']
```

I have found [this](https://regex101.com/r/YrQe0L/1), but I am not able to incorporate it to the code correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could get the matches instead of split `[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ -][A-Z][a-z]+)+(?= \([A-Z]{2,}\))|\w+` https://regex101.com/r/iUFDFf/1 but is based on the presence of repeating uppercase chars from the words before and only uppercase chars within the parenthesis. See https://ideone.com/SBzheb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match consecutive words starting with an uppercase char followed by 1+ lowercase chars with either a space or `-` in between to get a single match for *Multi-Criteria Decision Making*.

To match the other words, you can use an alternation `|` to match 1 or more word characters.

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ -][A-Z][a-z]+)*|\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J8eqJZ/1)

---

If there should be a part following with 2 or more uppercase chars between parenthesis, you could use a positive lookahead.

Note that the lookahead only checks for the presence of uppercase chars, it does not match the exact same uppercase chars from the preceding words.

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ -][A-Z][a-z]+)+(?= \([A-Z]{2,}\))|\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtDOcP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SBzheb)

```
import re
 
s = 'Multi-Criteria Decision Making (MCDM) is increasingly used in RE projects.'
pattern = r'[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ -][A-Z][a-z]+)+(?= \([A-Z]{2,}\))|\w+'
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Multi-Criteria Decision Making', 'MCDM', 'is', 'increasingly', 'used', 'in', 'RE', 'projects']
```

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/XuUop0 will be safer. Based on [how to match abbreviations with their meaning with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63634264/3832970)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes using a backreference for to match at least the first uppercase char will be a bit safer indeed. Nice solution :-) ++